# SpriteKit SKScene not resizing correctly to fit iPhone 12

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene

I've created a new SpriteKit project and want the scene to fill the screen entirely. I have defined the GameScene with iPhone 12 screen dimensions (390pt x 844pt) and specified the following in `GameViewController.swift`:

```
if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
    if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") {
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
        view.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

However, there is still a large amount of unoccupied space above and below the SKScene. I can't figure out what I've done wrong, and any help would be appreciated.

[image: Simulator screenshot]

Comment: Make sure to set the launch screen file: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/661269

Comment: @aheze This was the fix, thank you. Saved me a lot of frustration

Comment: It could be that your SKScene dimension are not large enough to fill the entire screen. Remember that aspect fill expands to the larger of the X or Y (sometimes causing the scene to be cropped). If the larger of the 2 is not large enough to fill the screen, then you might get what you have. Try using "scene.size = CGSize(width: 750, height: 1125)". Insert this code before presenting your scene. You can play around with the width and height values to suit your needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Fix (credit @aheze)**

As mentioned [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/661269), this can be fixed by setting the launch screen file in your project settings under App Icons and Launch Images.